# How to Filter multiple departments in DHTMLX Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, css, angular, dhtmlx

I am using the following gantt chart version
dhtmlxGantt v.4.1.19, licensed version.

Question: Need to filter multiple departments from gantt chart and table.

Currently, I am able to filter only one department at a time but I need to filter multiple departments with checkboxes in dropdown.

Department filter should as shown below 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The task is displayed or hidden depending on the value you return in the `onBeforeTaskDisplay` event handler(`true` to show, `false` to hide):
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_onbeforetaskdisplay_event.html

So, you need to add custom logic that will determine if the task should be displayed.
Here is an example of how it might be implemented:

https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/e79b73263

Comment: Above example is not working and I need to filter the departments as shown below as in the dropdown

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the information, that you need to add the year range first, then you can use the multiselect element, and both filters will be applied:
https://prnt.sc/qrn5az